# I need the year needs to be passed as a variable in the link so it can be grabbed via a get statement

Tags: php

My html page.
I have this line.

```
<a href="Player_Roster.php?inputyr=2011">2011</a><br />
```

My php page.
I have this line of code.

```
<?php
$inputyr = $_GET[inputyr];
$query = "SELECT * FROM players
WHERE playeryear = $inputyr;
ORDER BY number";
$players = mysql_query($query);
?>
```

I want my php page to do a query using the year 2011.

After I click on the link it opens the page.  It does show...
but the players don't fill in the table.  The query does work if I manually type in the 2011.

Comment: And what do you mean by "manually type in the 2011" ?

Comment: @Jeff: I deleted the link to your site for the time being. The code as it stands is just asking for some jerk to come and ruin your day, best not to advertise where it's at :P

Answer (score 1):

You had a extra semicolon in your query after `$inputyr`. Try the following.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM players
    WHERE playeryear = $inputyr
    ORDER BY number";
```

You should also be escaping anything you put into sql strings. In theory someone could do very bad things to your database right now with a properly crafted `$inputyr` value

```
//protect against sql injection
$inputyr = mysql_real_escape_string($inputyr)

$query = "SELECT * FROM players
    WHERE playeryear = $inputyr
    ORDER BY number";
```

Comment: We can't stress the escaping enough. Some alternative ways to do escaping: intval() for integers, PDO and prepared statements to skip database escaping altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes around $inputyr.

```
<?php
$inputyr = $_GET[inputyr];
$query = "SELECT * FROM players
WHERE playeryear = '$inputyr'
ORDER BY number";
$players = mysql_query($query);
?>
```